# Linux SNMP monitoring using Intermapper monitoring system

Tags: linux, snmp

I was wondering if anyone out there is using Intermapper SNMP Monitoring software?  I am able to monitor system resources in every Windows Servers by making sure that the SNMP Service is started, Service Agents are checked, Send authentication trap is checked, Community Names are defined and Accept SNMP packets from these hosts are defined as well in which its pointing to the ip address of the Intermapper SNMP Monitoring system.  My question is what would be the way/step by step procedure to configure this in Linux?  Aside from monitoring Windows Servers, I'd like to be able to monitor Linux Server as well.  Appreciate everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much special to SNMP configuration on linux. Net-SNMP is probably one of the more popular options. The process is basically the same on linux as windows. Just make sure SNMP is installed, configured, and allowed through the firewall. Check out

http://wiki.zenoss.org/Configure_SNMPv3

http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html

As far as installing the Net-SNMP packages, it depends on your distribution, as does firewall config.